# expo cli build for ios

Tags: react-native, expo

i want to build ios using expo manage When I run eas build -p ios
i get the following error
Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project

It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how

to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/

Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make

sure your project is set up correctly.

fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the

the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.

Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there

[stderr]

[!] Error building the application - see the log above

Error: The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Refer to "Xcode Logs" below for additional, more detailed logs.

i want to build ios for production using expo

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.